# Understand the topology of this 4-dimensional data.

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Now I have a set of 4 dimensional data points.

If I project them onto the first and second dimension, they look like figure 1.
[image: Figure 1: data projected to 1st and 2nd dimension]

If I project them onto the third and forth dimension, they look like figure 2. [image: Figure 2: data projected to 3rd and 4th dimension]

(Note that same color indicates same data point.)

I wonder if there is any known topology structure that fits the data.
I think the data is homeomorphic to the unit circle S1 but I am not familiar with (differential) topology.

The data and visualization code is available [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zwWKiZdDwdHF9recYXQsRFcw154UgLb9?usp=sharing) if anyone is interested.

---

Update 1:
This figure shows some of the combination of dimensions for better understanding the structure. [image: Figure 3]

---

Update 2:
Thanks to @AndrewD.Hwang. I plot the tracjectory $0.2(cos(2t+θ_0),sin(2t+θ_0),sint,−cost)$, where $θ_0=7/4\pi$ and $t\in[0,2\pi]$. This equation almost fits the data!! [image: Figure 4]

Comment: After filling in the dots, you can conclude is that your data is contained in the product of two circles, usually called the 2-dimensional torus. You cannot conclude that it is the circle (it might be the entire torus for instance).

Comment: This appears to be a closed curve. As such it is topologically a circle, no matter how many dimensions it is embedded in. This partcular closed curve appears to be similar to ellipses in 3D that are at 45 a degree slant to the coordinate planes, with en eccentricity to project onto near-circles on those planes. It might be helpful to plot the other four dimensional pairings (1-3, 1-4, 2-3, 2-4) to get a better idea of the behavior. Better yet would be the three 3D graphs where only one dimension is suppressed.

Comment: If $\theta_0 \approx 7\pi/4$ is the angle in the top projection where the color "jumps" from yellow to purple, your data look pretty close to $0.2(\cos(2t + \theta_0), \sin(2t + \theta_0), \sin t, -\cos t)$ for evenly-spaced $t$ in $[0, 2\pi]$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you for suggestion, I update the post!!

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you for your comment, this equation fits perfectly.